# How to limit the stepsize using python's scipy.stats.levy?

Tags: python, random, scipy

I am trying to model a Levy walk using [`scipy.stats.levy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levy.html). It works fine except for the fact that there are a few steps which are VERY large and I would like to know if there is a proper way to limit the stepsize.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import uniform
from scipy.stats import levy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def levy_walk( n ):

    # uniformly distributed angles
    angle = uniform.rvs( size=(n,), loc=.0, scale=2.*np.pi )

    # levy distributed step length
    r = levy.rvs( size=n )

    # x and y coordinates (position added to previous coordinate --> cum. sum)
    x = np.cumsum( r * np.cos(angle) )
    y = np.cumsum( r * np.sin(angle) )

    return np.array( (x, y, r, angle) )

# number of steps to simulate
n = 500

# get levy walk (strictly speaking, it seems to be a flight)
foo = levy_walk( n )

# initialize figure
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(14,6) )

# plot 2D random walk with Levy stepsize
ax1 = fig.add_subplot( 1,2,1 )
ax1.plot( foo[0,:], foo[1,:] )
ax1.set_xlabel( 'x' )
ax1.set_ylabel( 'y' )
ax1.set_title( '2D Levy flight' )

# plot histogram
ax2 = fig.add_subplot( 1,2,2 )
num_bins = n/10
ax2.hist( foo[2,:], bins=n/10 )
ax2.set_yscale( 'log' )
ax2.set_xlabel( 'stepsize' )
ax2.set_title( 'histogram' )

plt.show()
```

And this is an example output figure where you can clearly see the occurrence of very few but VERY large steps:

[image: 2D Lévy flight (walk)]

So, my question is what is the proper way to limit the step size ? (Using the `scale` option does not really help as it only scales everything down)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I just wanted to visualize a random walk process with a Levy walk stepsize, that's all (I recently had a discussion with a friend about Brownian motion and Levy walks and wanted to have a look at it myself by running a few simulations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually behaving the way it should.  The [expected value of a Levy distribution is ∞](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution), it is extremely "fat-tailed".  If that's the distribution you're using then you're going to get a fair number of monstrously large values.  If you truncate those, it's not a Levy distribution.  So no, there's not a proper way to limit the step sizes while using a Levy distribution.  Your alternative is to use a different distribution for the step size if the results you're getting don't match observational data or your intuition.

Comment: ohhh, I forgot about the difference between *fat-tailed* and *heavy-tailed*, thanks for reminding me. (I guess animals are not really doing proper Levy walks then....)

Answer (score 1):

Levy flight is actually based on Levy distribution functions. You could adjust alpha and beta of the function to reach the simulation effects that you want. In addition, you may try the "levy_stable" in scipy.stats rather than the "levy", where you can set up the arguments such as alpha and beta. In this way, the length of travels won't be extremely long. For more info about the setting of functions, please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight.
[alpha=2,beta=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jSpO.png)[alpha=1,beta=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8kuR.png)